# How to connect to a Sequelize database in a Firebase cloud function?

Tags: firebase, sequelize.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

I have a Firebase cloud function which calls into a Google Cloud SQL instance. With Cloud SQL, an instance connection name like `project:region:instance` is provided for connecting. Where does that go when connecting with Sequelize which has a constructor which looks like `Sequelize(dbName, user, password)`?

Where does the instance connection name go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the answer now. You set the `host` option to the instance connection name when initializing Sequelize.

Comment: can you share your entire configuration for the `Sequelize` constructor?

Comment: @MaksymilianMajer set DATABASE_URL env and put this on your config.json
```
  "production": {
    "database": "database_production",
    "use_env_variable": "DATABASE_URL",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  }
```